# I get undefined value when I tried to get my TAG in prisma?

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

Hello studying CRUD of NextJS+TypeScript+Prisma with TanstackQuery, so I'm trying to render the `tag.name`, but I get `undefined error` when I tried to fetch it.

[image]

This is my Homepage wherein I fetch all data and the pass it to my `<PostCard />`.

```
async function getPost() {
  const response = await db.post.findMany({
    select: {
      id: true,
      title: true,
      content: true,
    },
    orderBy: {
      createdAt: 'desc'
    }
  })

  return response
}

const Home = async () => {
  
  const posts = await getPost();

  return (
    <main>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <PostCard key={post.id} post={post} />
      ))}
    </main>
  );
};
```

This is my PostCard wherein I get the props from my homepage.

```
import { Tag } from "@prisma/client";
interface PostCardProps {
  post: {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    content:string,
    tag: Tag

  }
}

const PostCard = ({post}:PostCardProps) => {

  const {title, content, tag} = post
  

  return (
    <div>
        <h2 className="card-title">{title}</h2>
        <p>{content}</p>
        <div className="card-actions justify-end">
            <Link href="/blog/1">
                Read more...
            </Link>
        </div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

This is my Prisma.Schema for relational of both post and tags,

```
model Tag {
  id   String @id @default(cuid())
  name String @db.VarChar(100)
  Post Post[]
}

model Post {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  title String @db.VarChar(225)
  content String

  tagId String
  Tag Tag @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm so bad, haha I get it now, in my Prisma.Schema I put

```
model Post {
  id    String @id @default(cuid())
  title String @db.VarChar(225)
  content String

  tagId String
  Tag Tag @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
}
```

I change this.

```
  Tag Tag @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
```

to

```
  tag Tag @relation(fields: [tagId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)
```

Additionally, I added.

```
tag: true
```

in my `GetPosts`